# OrientDB - How to use fetchPlan in BATCH OrientJS script

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I would like to fetch linked entities in BATCH script, but it returns me only the RecordIds.

```
begin;
let count = select count(*) from Company;
let companies = select from Company ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 25 FETCHPLAN type:1 portfolios:1;
commit;
return [$count, $companies];
```

Using `OrientDB Server v2.2.17`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
begin;
let count = select count(*) from Company;
let companies = select name from Company ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 25 FETCHPLAN type:1 portfolios:1;
commit;
return [$count, $companies];
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Michela

Comment: Thank you for your reply @michela-bonizzi . But type and portfolios are not fetched and are only Rids